# Multi Checkbox are not getting checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, debugging

I'm working on the simple bootstrap table and I'm using checkboxes like this.

[image: Check this image (Design of the checkboxies)]

The checked values are saved in the state but the checkbox is still unchecked thats my issue.

[image: Checkbox is not getting checked]

Now when I click on the checkbox I'm sorting the values in a state, but the issue I am facing is when I double-click on the checkbox become tick, and when I single click it won't tick on the checkbox.

My Code:

```
const handelAddSelectOrders = (e, data) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    setSelectedOrders((prevSelectedOrders) => {
      if (isChecked) {
        return [...prevSelectedOrders, data];
      } else {
        return prevSelectedOrders.filter((item) => item !== data);
      }
    });
  };

    <input onChange={(e) => handelAddSelectOrders(e, el)} className="form-check-input"
      value={el?._id} type="checkbox" name={`${el?._id}`} checked={selectedOrders.includes(el)}
     />
```

Comment: Remove the `value` attribute, there is already the `checked` one

Comment: @underflow I resolved the issue. I'm using e.preventDefault(); so when I removed that line It works perfectly fine.